# Is there an Android standard for specifying home screen icons for web apps?

Tags: android, web-applications

Apple defines 57x57 pixel images linked with rel="apple-touch-icon[-precomposed]". I’m having a hard time figuring out if there is any standard equivalent for the Android ecosystem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there it is :

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html

Comment: Hey, I already checked out those pages, and they did mention a number of icon sizes I would want to supply if building an actual Android app, but did not mention any way to specify these icons from a web page. Is pinning a web page to the launcher like an app simply not a concept Android supports as a platform? They’re just bookmarks, if your particular flavor of Androids allows bookmarks to be added to the launcher?